# What is the reasoning behind the previous Islamic wars given a predestined lifespan?

Tags: quran, hadith, death, war

Apparently in Islam, the day you die has already been set by God

http://quran.com/6/2

> It is He who created you from clay and then decreed a term and a
>   specified time [known] to Him; then [still] you are in dispute.

So what is the purpose of war?  I mean if those soldiers/mujahids have their dates already set, it won't matter if they die at war or die while crossing the road, they will die on the date set.

So why was war done in islam in the past?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Abandoning Jihad does not delay your death from appointed time nor does participating in it hasten your death.

Allah says in Qur'an:

> وَلِيَعْلَمَ الَّذِينَ نَافَقُوا  وَقِيلَ لَهُمْ تَعَالَوْا
>   قَاتِلُوا فِي سَبِيلِ اللَّـهِ أَوِ ادْفَعُوا  قَالُوا لَوْ نَعْلَمُ
>   قِتَالًا لَّاتَّبَعْنَاكُمْ  هُمْ لِلْكُفْرِ‌ يَوْمَئِذٍ أَقْرَ‌بُ
>   مِنْهُمْ لِلْإِيمَانِ  يَقُولُونَ بِأَفْوَاهِهِم مَّا لَيْسَ فِي
>   قُلُوبِهِمْ  وَاللَّـهُ أَعْلَمُ بِمَا يَكْتُمُونَ
>
> الَّذِينَ قَالُوا لِإِخْوَانِهِمْ وَقَعَدُوا لَوْ أَطَاعُونَا مَا
>   قُتِلُوا  قُلْ فَادْرَ‌ءُوا عَنْ أَنفُسِكُمُ الْمَوْتَ إِن كُنتُمْ
>   صَادِقِينَ
>
> And that He might make evident those who are hypocrites.  For it was said to them, "Come, fight in the way of Allah or [at least] defend." They said, "If we had known [there would be] fighting, we would have followed you." They were nearer to disbelief that day than to faith, saying with their mouths what was not in their hearts. And Allah is most Knowing of what they conceal -
>
> Those who said about their brothers while sitting [at home], "If they
>   had obeyed us, they would not have been killed." Say, **"Then prevent
>   death from yourselves, if you should be truthful."** [**[Qur'an 3:167-168]**](http://quran.com/3/167-168)

In the above Ayah Allah challenges those who say sitting at home will prevent the death and he says to them "prevent death from yourselves if your are truthful". And they know they can't.

Because Allah says and he answers the same question you asked in Surah An-Nisa' (emphasis mine)

> أَلَمْ تَرَ‌ إِلَى الَّذِينَ قِيلَ لَهُمْ كُفُّوا أَيْدِيَكُمْ
>   وَأَقِيمُوا الصَّلَاةَ وَآتُوا الزَّكَاةَ فَلَمَّا كُتِبَ عَلَيْهِمُ
>   الْقِتَالُ إِذَا فَرِ‌يقٌ مِّنْهُمْ يَخْشَوْنَ النَّاسَ كَخَشْيَةِ
>   اللَّـهِ أَوْ أَشَدَّ خَشْيَةً  وَقَالُوا رَ‌بَّنَا لِمَ كَتَبْتَ
>   عَلَيْنَا الْقِتَالَ لَوْلَا أَخَّرْ‌تَنَا إِلَىٰ أَجَلٍ قَرِ‌يبٍ 
>   قُلْ مَتَاعُ الدُّنْيَا قَلِيلٌ وَالْآخِرَ‌ةُ خَيْرٌ‌ لِّمَنِ اتَّقَىٰ
>   وَلَا تُظْلَمُونَ فَتِيلًا
>
> أَيْنَمَا تَكُونُوا يُدْرِ‌ككُّمُ الْمَوْتُ وَلَوْ كُنتُمْ فِي
>   بُرُ‌وجٍ مُّشَيَّدَةٍ  وَإِن تُصِبْهُمْ حَسَنَةٌ يَقُولُوا هَـٰذِهِ
>   مِنْ عِندِ اللَّـهِ  وَإِن تُصِبْهُمْ سَيِّئَةٌ يَقُولُوا هَـٰذِهِ
>   مِنْ عِندِكَ  قُلْ كُلٌّ مِّنْ عِندِ اللَّـهِ  فَمَالِ هَـٰؤُلَاءِ
>   الْقَوْمِ لَا يَكَادُونَ يَفْقَهُونَ حَدِيثًا
>
> Have you not seen those who were told, "Restrain your hands [from
>   fighting] and establish prayer and give zakah"? But then when fighting
>   was ordained for them, at once a party of them feared men as they fear
>   Allah or with [even] greater fear. **They said, "Our Lord, why have You
>   decreed upon us fighting? If only You had postponed [it for] us for a
>   short time." Say, The enjoyment of this world is little, and the
>   Hereafter is better for he who fears Allah . And injustice will not be
>   done to you, [even] as much as a thread [inside a date seed]."**
>
> **Wherever you may be, death will overtake you, even if you should be
>   within towers of lofty construction.** But if good comes to them, they
>   say, "This is from Allah "; and if evil befalls them, they say, "This
>   is from you." Say, "All [things] are from Allah ." So what is [the
>   matter] with those people that they can hardly understand any
>   statement? [**[Qur'an 4:77-78]**](http://quran.com/4/77-78)

In this context, as an example, it is mentioned in [tafseer of Ibn Kathir](http://abdurrahman.org/qurantafseer/ibnkathir/ibnkathir_web/2.6575.html) (rahimahullah)

> Abu Sulayman, Khalid bin Al-Walid, the commander of the Muslim armies,
>   the veteran among Muslim soldiers, the protector of Islam and the
>   Sword of Allah that was raised above His enemies, said while dying, "I
>   have participated in so-and-so number of battles. There is not a part
>   of my body, but suffered a shot (of an arrow), a stab (of a spear) or
>   a strike (of a sword). Yet, here I am, I die on my bed just as the
>   camel dies! May the eyes of the cowards never taste sleep.'' He, may
>   Allah be pleased with him, was sorry and in pain because he did not
>   die as martyr in battle. He was sad that he had to die on his bed!

So, wishing for death while fighting in the cause of Allah will need not make it happen and also, staying away from it will not delay the death. Indeed, the affair of every living thing is with Allah. And it's life is predestined. But, for those who fight in the cause of Allah, they have a reward and those who martyr, they have a reward too. So, why sit at home and lose the opportunity to please Allah and earn his reward. That is why the Prophet (salallahu alayhi wassalam) and his companions fought wars against enemies of Allah.